# What to do when only a portion of training/testing data generates confident predictions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a general question on machine learning that can be applied to any algorithm. Suppose I have a particular problem, let us say soccer team winning/losing prediction. The features I choose are the amount of sleep each player gets before the game, sentiment analysis on news coverage, etc etc.

In this scenario, there is a pattern or correlation (something only a machine learning algorithm can pick up on) that only occurs around 5% of the time. But when it occurs, it is very predictive of the upcoming match.

How do you setup a machine learning algorithm to handle such a case in which it has the ability to discard most samples as noise. For example, consider a binary SVM. If there was a way to discard most of the “noisy” samples, a lot less overfitting would occur because the hyperplane would not have to eliminate error from these samples.

Regularization would help in this case, but due to the very low percentage of predictive information, is there a way we can code the algorithm to discard these samples in training and refuse to predict certain test data samples?

I have also read into confidence intervals but they seem more of an analytic tool to me than something to use in the algorithm.

I was thinking that using another ml algorithm which uses the same features to decide which testing samples are keepers might be a good idea.

Any answers using any machine learning algorithm (e.g. svm, neural net, random forest) as an example would be much appreciated. Any suggestions on where to look would be great as well (google is usually my friend, but not this time). Please let me know if I can rephrase the question better. Thanks.